# UML - BCED Approach

Tags: uml, entity, controls

I have a question for you.

In the BCED approach, whe have 4 package (Boundary, Control, Entity, Database), in which there are many classes with some responsability. Who is responsible to istantiate and destroy objects in the Entity package? Control's objects or Entity's object?

I'll explain better.

For example, we have 1 controller class and 2 entity classes, linked to each other by an association. Suppose that we have to use the 2 objects of 2 separated classes in the entity.
So, the controller class istantiate both object of the entity like this:

```
//In the controller:

create_objects(){
Entity1 e1=new Entity1;
Entity2 e2=new Entity2;
 }
```

or the controller istantiate only the first class object that instantiates, in turn, the second class object (I remember to you that the entity classes are linked!!), like this:

```
//In the controller:

create_objects(){
Entity1 e1=new Entity1;
 }

//In the Entity1:

create_object_2(){
Entity2 e2=new Entity2;
 }
```

Thank you in advance and sorry for the English! :)

Answer (score 0):

BCED is an architectural view at the Model-View-Controller Pattern.

And in the last there is a principle: In Model/Entity or in View/Boundary layers the components are independent on each other. All interdependence is in the Controller layer. So, the classic behaviour is the first one - when you create both Entity classes from controller.

But classes are not components. And on this abstraction level the rule is far from being so strict. For classes take it not as a rule, but as a nice target: try to keep your Entity classes being more independent on each other.

But if you have an Entity1 that is a composition of Entity2 class with something else, then the second variant is the only sensible one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. When I create these diagrams, first I draw the System Domain Model, which contains the main classes of the domain of the problem. Then, I transfer all classes (or, alternatively, classes more important) of the SDM in the Entity package, with all their associations.

So, if I understand correctly, the entity classes only have few methods for the interfacing with the Database, while the control classes have all the logic of the program, and works with multiple entity classes, right??

Comment: @user3370379  the control classes have all the BUSINESS/DOMAIN logic of the program. The rules, that you have set yourself, for example, that large frame should be shown green, or that such Entity classes are mapped to such tables, does not belong to the logic of domain. It is only the ways of the tools of your choice. And class mapping to DB does not belong to functions of Controller.